# Templates arguments not fulfulling all requirements

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14

This is possible:

```
struct A {
    //void f();  < not declared in struct A
};

template<typename T>
struct Wrapper {
    T t;
    void call_f() { t.f(); }
};

int main() {
    Wrapper<A> w;
}
```

This compiled fine, as long as `w.call_f()` is not called. `w.call_f()` can not be instantiated because `A::f` does not exist.

I'm having a situation with such a wrapper template that gets used with different `T` types, which do not always implement all parts of the interface. (Mainly to avoid code duplication).

This does not work:

```
struct A {
    //using i_type = int;   < not declared/defined
};

template<typename T>
struct Wrapper {
    using its_i_type = typename T::i_type;
       // compile error, even if `i_type` gets never used
};

int main() {
    Wrapper<A> w;
}
```

neither does this:

```
struct A {
    //using i_type = int;   < not declared/defined
};

template<typename T>
struct Wrapper {
    typename T::i_type call_f() { return 0; }
       // does not compile, even if `call_f()` is never instantiated
};

int main() {
    Wrapper<A> w;
}
```

Is there a good way to handle these situations, without a lot of code duplication (like a specialization for `Wrapper`, etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can defer the type deduction of `its_i_type`. Basically, you create a simple wrapper that you must go through.

---

To extend it to other types you require, (I wanted to suggest `type_traits`-like solution, but since you don't want specializations) you could define all the types you need:

```
template<typename T>
struct Wrapper {
private:
    template<typename U> struct i_typper { using type = typename U::i_type; };
    template<typename U> struct k_typper { using type = typename U::k_type; };
    template<typename U> struct p_typper { using type = typename U::p_type; };
public:
    using i_trait = i_typper<T>;
    using k_trait = k_typper<T>;
    using p_trait = p_typper<T>;
};
```

Example:

```
struct A { using i_type = int; };
struct B { using i_type = int;    using k_type = float; };

int main() {
    Wrapper<A> w;   //Works now.

    Wrapper<A>::i_trait::type  mk1;  //Works
    Wrapper<A>::k_trait::type  mk2;  //Fails, not defined
    Wrapper<B>::i_trait::type  mk3;  //Works
    Wrapper<B>::k_trait::type  mk4;  //Works
}
```

---

For the case of:

```
template<typename T>
struct Wrapper {
    typename T::i_type call_f() { return 0; }
       // does not compile, even if `call_f()` is never instantiated
};
```

You have few options here:

1. make that function a member function template
2. Use some form of `type_traits` mechanism, which will still involve specialization
3. Go the way of abstracting common `Wrapper` stuff in a base class `WrapperBase`;

For the first option, you'll have to modify it a bit to further [defer deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts)

```
template<typename T>
struct Wrapper {
private:
    template<typename U, typename> struct i_typper { using type = typename U::i_type; };
    template<typename U, typename> struct k_typper { using type = typename U::k_type; };
    template<typename U, typename> struct p_typper { using type = typename U::p_type; };
public:
    using i_trait = i_typper<T, void>;
    using k_trait = k_typper<T, void>;
    using p_trait = p_typper<T, void>;

    template<typename U = void>
    typename k_typper<T, U>::type call_f() { return 0; }
};
```

I'll leave the second option as an exercise: (it may end up being something like:

```
template<typename T>
struct wrapper_traits {
    ....
};

template<>
struct wrapper_traits<A>{
   using ....
};

template<typename T>
struct Wrapper {
   ....
public:
    using i_trait = wrapper_traits<T>;
    using k_trait = wrapper_traits<T>;
    using p_trait = wrapper_traits<T>;
};
```

[Jarod's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38795728/1621391) is simpler. But this will work if you do not have access to `std::experimental`, or your company code policy forbids you...

Comment: And how about a `call_f` that returns `i_type`?

Comment: @aschepler, then it will fail. In that case, I'll either make  `call_f` a template member function or I'll go with the `type_trait`-like solution, which will involve specializations

Comment: *"You have two options [..] 1.[..]2.[..]3.[..]"* :-) (I know, multiple edit).

Answer (score 2):

With `std::experimental::is_detected`, you may do

```
template<typename T>
using i_type_t = typename T::i_type;

template<typename T>
struct Wrapper {
    using its_i_type = typename std::experimental::detected_t<i_type_t, T>;
       // would be T::i_type or std::experimental::nonesuch
};
```

Or to better handle case, something like:

```
template<typename T, bool = std::experimental::is_detected<i_type_t, T>::value>
struct WrapperWithIType {
    // Empty for false case.
};

template<typename T>
struct WrapperWithIType<T, true> {
    using its_i_type = i_type_t<T>;

    its_i_type call_f() { return 0; }
};
```

and then

```
template<typename T>
struct Wrapper : WrapperWithIType<T> {
    // Common stuff
};
```

Comment: @WhiZTiM it's in a TS (technical specification, and currently works in g++-6).